# The domain of the function

Tags: functions

What is the domain of this function:
$$f(x) = 2x^{5/3} + 5 x^{2/3}$$

I think that it is $\mathbb R$, but gnuplot plots it only as $x\ge0$.

**EDIT**
How to compute for negative $x$

$\frac{10}{3} x^{\frac{2}{3}}+\frac{10}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}>0$

$\frac{10}{3} x^{\frac{2}{3}}+\frac{10}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}<0$

$>$ holds for $(-\infty;-1)$ and $<$ holds for $(-1;0)$

but I got the reverse result:

$x^{\frac{2}{3}} < -x^{-\frac{1}{3}}$

$x < -1$

Comment: I see no reason why the domain wouldn’t be R. It is certainly defined for negative values of x.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note unless a program does something like symbolic computations, values like $\frac{1}{3}$ will only be stored *approximately*. Thus, the program acts on them based on what they're stored as, not what they actually are.

Comment: OK, thank you very much

Comment: Could you help me with edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This step is correct:

> $x^{\frac{2}{3}} < -x^{-\frac{1}{3}}$

You have to be careful because when $x$ is negative, dividing by $x^{-\frac{1}{3}}$ flips the inequality sign. Continue by splitting into two cases: when $x$ is either positive or negative.

When $x$ is positive, we get $x < -1$, so there are no positive solutions for $x$.

When $x$ is negative, we get $x > -1$.

Combining these two inequalities gives $-1 < x < 0$.

Comment: Oh, yes, many thanks